# Aliases in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, notepad++, alias, command-prompt

I have added `notepad++.exe` to my Path in environment variables.

Now in command prompt, `notepad++.exe filename.txt` opens the `filename.txt`. But I want to do just `np filename.txt` to open the file.

I tried using `DOSKEY np=notepad++`. But it is just bringing to the forefront an already opened Notepad++ without opening the file. How can I make it open the file?

Comment: Change the executable name to anything you want.  You can do this from the File Explorer!

Answer (score 632, accepted):

To add to josh's answer,

you may make the alias(es) *persistent* with the following steps,

1. Create a .bat or .cmd file with your `DOSKEY` commands.
2. Run regedit and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
3. Add String Value entry with the name `AutoRun` and the *full* path of your .bat/.cmd file.

   For example, `%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd`, replacing the initial segment of the path with `%USERPROFILE%` is useful for syncing among multiple machines.

This way, every time cmd is run, the aliases are loaded.

**For Windows 10 or Windows 11**, add the entry to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` instead.

(For Windows 11, also note that by default the "Terminal App" points to PowerShell. Search "cmd" for command prompt.)

For completeness, here is a template to illustrate the kind of aliases one may find useful.

```
@echo off

:: Temporary system path at cmd startup

set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\"

:: Add to path by command

DOSKEY add_python26=set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Python26\"
DOSKEY add_python33=set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Python33\"

:: Commands

DOSKEY ls=dir /B $*
DOSKEY sublime=sublime_text $*  
    ::sublime_text.exe is name of the executable. By adding a temporary entry to system path, we don't have to write the whole directory anymore.
DOSKEY gsp="C:\Program Files (x86)\Sketchpad5\GSP505en.exe"
DOSKEY alias=notepad %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\alias.cmd

:: Common directories

DOSKEY dropbox=cd "%USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\$*"
DOSKEY research=cd %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\Research\
```

---

- Note that the `$*` syntax works after a directory string as well as an executable which takes in arguments. So in the above example, the user-defined command `dropbox research` points to the same directory as `research`.
- As Rivenfall pointed out, it is a good idea to include a command that allows for convenient editing of the `alias.cmd` file. See `alias` above. If you are in a cmd session, enter `cmd` to restart cmd and reload the `alias.cmd` file.

---

When I searched the internet for an answer to the question, somehow the discussions were either focused on persistence only or on some usage of DOSKEY only. I hope someone will benefit from these two aspects being together here!

---

Here's a `.reg` file to help you install the `alias.cmd`. It's set now as an example to a dropbox folder as suggested above.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="%USERPROFILE%\\alias.cmd"
```

---

For single-user applications, the above will do. Nevertheless, there are situations where it is necessary to check whether `alias.cmd` exists first in the registry key. See example below.

In a `C:\Users\Public\init.cmd` file hosting potentially cross-user configurations:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Add other configurations as needed
IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd" ( CALL "%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd" )
```

The registry key should be updated correspondly to `C:\Users\Public\init.cmd` or, using the `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"AutoRun"="C:\\Users\\Public\\init.cmd"
```

Comment: exactly what I needed; works perfectly; I recommend adding a doskey to actually edit the env.cmd file

Comment: This is naive and inefficient. The autorun batch file will be run for every instance of cmd.exe, including the `system` function. It needs to exit if a certain variable (e.g. `AUTORUN`) is defined. Otherwise set up the environment (`set AUTORUN=1`) and set up doskey in a single pass using the macrofile option instead of running doskey.exe to define each alias.

Comment: @Argyll thanks for your answer, However every time I open a cmd window , all of my DOSKEY commands are printed on the windows. Is there a way to run it on the background.

Comment: I think the `@echo off` command should be able to turn the printing off.

Comment: @eryksun can you post or link to a less naive example? I know how to exit if autorun is defined, but confused over how to set or unset it in the first place without having already run CMD.

Comment: using .cmd did not work for me, although using .bat did

Comment: If you don't want to deal with editing register values, press `Start`, type `cmd`, right click `cmd` and open the location, right click `cmd.exe` and open properties, then add `/k path_to_bat_file.bat`.

Comment: What's the replacement for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` in the present day? I can't seem to find that path in regedit anymore

Comment: @Jan: I don't have Win 10 to find out. Search up on command prompt in win 10? I remember cmd being a limited version in win 10 from my brief encounters with them.

Comment: @Argyll Guess I could've googled it first -- This article looks promising: https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/three-methods-to-disable-autorun-in-windows-10/ Not by my Windows 10 machine atm but I'll check back here when I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: @Jan: good luck. Let me know if you find anything. Increasingly more people may need it now that Win 7 is going to stop receiving updates.

Comment: @Jan did you manage to find anything in that article that worked? I still wasn't able to find an equivalent.

Comment: @Jan For me, it was in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`. I used the Edit->Find functionality in the Registry Editor to find it.

Comment: I just got a new computer with win 10. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` works for me.

Comment: I like this. A similar option is to put in the autorun: `doskey /macrofile="%USERPROFILE%\alias"`. And next put the aliases in the 'alias' file, without the 'doskey' part. A solution an admin could use to restrict autorun definitions to aliases a user could self-make. Preventing users from autorunning other stuff.

Comment: Please note that this solution may cause problems down the line (I have had build with automated tools strangely fail for seemingly no reason at all).
It may be best to have a globally accessible `bat` file with calls the `%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd` only if defined. For instance...

`IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd" ( CALL "%USERPROFILE%\alias.cmd")`

This should prevent "leakage" of non-existing configuration errors in subcommand prompts (node, maven, ...)

Comment: @Markio: Good point. Would you like to edit it into the answer? (Only after verifying the code ofc.)

Comment: @Markio: An edit does need to integrate into the answer in style as well. So you see, phrases starting with "I would instead..." wouldn't make sense when others read the edited answer. So I am going to approve the edit. But as well, I'll make the style changes to your edit. (Hopefully other reviewers see my reasoning here. After all, **I did not check that the new files work**, which I otherwise should do before approving edits.) Thank you for your contribution in any case!

Comment: @Jan: You can create a "Command Processor" key by hand under HKCU\Software\Microsoft (with the Autorun string value in it). Works well for me under Win10.

Comment: Nice works. If you want to switch jdk, maybe you can add something like this.`DOSKEY setjdk8=set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301$tset PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin;%PATH%;
DOSKEY setjdk17=set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17$tset PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;%PATH%;` Be care of `$t`, not around spaces allowed here.

Comment: I don't recommend using the registry option at all, as it can have many undesired consequences and affect other programs, specially if current directory is changed, as explained here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433. It's better to edit the command prompt shortcut (or duplicate it) to run a script at start with /k.

Comment: I recommend `DOSKEY ls=dir /B "$*"`

Comment: @imjosh: forgive my laziness to look/try things up/out. Why `""`?

Comment: @Argyll "$*" let's you pass a path from the alias to the command. So `ls .\path\to\directory` will work.  I think the `""` are required so doskey knows it's not a literal string.

Comment: @imjosh: the use case makes sense. I edited accordingly. Didn't include `""`. Wrapping input with `""` is something the user can (also) do. Though it may be interesting to double-check how cmd unwraps layers of `""`.

Comment: Maybe update to something similar "For Windows 11 and 10, add the entry to..." ? 
Now I thought the first file path was for Windows 11 as I didn't check the publish date at first. Thank you.

Answer (score 290):

You need to pass the parameters, try this:

```
doskey np=notepad++.exe $*
```

> **Edit** (responding to Romonov's comment) Q: *Is there any way I can make the command prompt remember so I don't have to run this each time I open a new command prompt?*

`doskey` is a textual command that is interpreted by the command processor (e.g. cmd.exe), it can't know to modify state in some other process (especially one that hasn't started yet).

People that use `doskey` to setup their initial command shell environments typically use the `/K` option (often via a shortcut) to run a batch file which does all the common setup (like- set window's title, colors, etc).

```
cmd.exe /K env.cmd
```

env.cmd:

```
title "Foo Bar"
doskey np=notepad++.exe $*
...
```

Comment: This works for the command prompt in which I run this command. But if I close the window and open a new command prompt. It doesn't remember the np command. Is there any way I can make the command prompt remember so I don't have to run this each time I open a new command prompt?

Comment: Same behavior without changing the PATH: `doskey npp="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" $*`

Comment: doskey.exe has nothing to do with cmd.exe. It sets an alias for the current or a specified executable in the console window, which is hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. Console aliases are matched and substituted at the beginning of a line of input before the client application (e.g. cmd.exe or powershell.exe) reads the line. They can't be used generically as commands, e.g. not in batch files or piped into.

Comment: Hi, I have used this with cmder to open phpstorm...it opens phpstorm but it keeps opening my last opened project and not the project directory I am currently in...How do I get this to open whichever DIR I am in?

Comment: @PA-GW: Did you use "phpstorm $*" in the doskey command? Did you try `phpstorm .` (note the dot as a shortcut for "current dir").

Comment: This method works very well with Windows Terminal since you can give `/K env.cmd` in the `Command line` attribute

Answer (score 231):

If you're just going for some simple commands, you could follow these steps:

1. Create a folder called **C:\Aliases**
2. Add **C:\Aliases** to your path (so any files in it will be found every time)
3. Create a **.bat** file in C:\Aliases for each of the aliases you want

Maybe overkill, but unlike the (otherwise excellent) answer from @Argyll, this solves the problem of this loading every time.

For instance, I have a file called **dig2.bat** with the following in it:

```
@echo off
echo.
dig +noall +answer %1
```

Your **np** file would just have the following:

```
@echo off
echo.
notepad++.exe %1
```

Then just add the **C:\Aliases** folder to your PATH environment variable. If you have CMD or PowerShell already opened you will need to restart it.

FWIW, I have about 20 aliases (separate .bat files) in my C:\Aliases directory - I just create new ones as necessary. Maybe not the neatest, but it works fine.

**UPDATE**: Per an excellent suggestion from user @Mav, it's even better to use **%*** rather than **%1**, so you can pass multiple files to the command, e.g.:

```
@echo off
echo.
notepad++.exe %*
```

That way, you could do this:

```
np c:\temp\abc.txt c:\temp\def.txt c:\temp\ghi.txt
```

and it will open all 3 files.

Comment: If you don't want your commandline to wait on closing notepad++, then you can use
`@echo off
START notepad++.exe %*`

Comment: I personally do use this method for a long time. This is one such very easy to do method if someone does not want to go on the way of `doskey`.

Comment: One advantage of this method (cmd files as aliases) is that if you use WSL (Linux subsystem for Windows) these cmds are available in bash as well.  Though often (depending what you are aliasing) you need to do some path manipulation using wslpath.sh or similar before you call the cmd file

Comment: This solution won't work for things like `DOSKEY ls=ls --color=auto &*`.

Comment: @Qwerty, in a comment on another answer above, I pointed out that I *never* create aliases with the same name as the underlying command, so I guess it never occurred to me! Actually, couldn't you fully qualify the `ls` command within your `.bat` file?

Comment: @roryhewitt Oh yes, specifying the full path to the `ls.exe` should definitely work. Good point. I have used the doskey alternative though.

Comment: wow! though it is a lengthy solution but amazing simple and easy to implement

Comment: Might want to add %* instead of %1 to pass in all the arguments as opposed to just the first.

Comment: @Mav - good point. In these examples, there's only a single argument anyway, but your point is well taken.

Comment: Just allowed myself to apply a little improvement which I think was intended. %1 just forwards the first parameter, $* all of them. See https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html for reference.

Comment: Great! Now I can have PHP without need to install it, just using devilbox for docker and adding `docker exec --user devilbox dvlbx_php_1 php %*`

Comment: What's the `echo.` for?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman it just adds a blank line in the terminal output. Not really necessary in this case (where I'm opening an application), but in some cases that blank line makes it easier to see things

Comment: Fantastic! Great with making an alias for lua.

Answer (score 46):

Alternatively you can use [`cmder`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) which lets you add aliases just like linux:

```
alias subl="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe" $*
```

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question. It is important for people from a Linux background to understand that there is an alternative to Windows CMDs that can suit their immediate needs.

Comment: There are quite a few alternatives.  Git for Windows comes with one, "git-bash".

Comment: To add alias in Cmder, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54478765/6064933).

Comment: Hi, I have used this with cmder to open phpstorm...it opens phpstorm but it keeps opening my last opened project and not the project directory I am currently in...How do I get this to open whichever DIR I am in?

Comment: @PA-GW You might want to add `.` as argument to phpstorm to tell it to open the current directory. See [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/opening-files-from-command-line.html#) help entry from Jetbrains for more info and [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#) for other command line options for phpstorm.

Comment: Agree that whilst this doesn't answer the question, it answers the need better for many who will search for this question.

Answer (score 37):

Given that you added notepad++.exe to your PATH variable, it's extra simple.
Create a file in your System32 folder called `np.bat` with the following code:

```
@echo off
call notepad++.exe %*
```

The `%*` passes along all arguments you give the `np` command to the `notepad++.exe` command.

**EDIT:**
You will need admin access to save files to the System32 folder, which was a bit wonky for me. I just created the file somewhere else and moved it to System32 manually.

Comment: I already have a folder of little .bat utility files so I like this better than messing with the registry or a .cmd file

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't work identically to calling Notepad++ directly. If you use wildcards in the filename you're opening, and call NPP directly, it works, e.g. you can do `"notepad++.exe *somefiles*"` and matching files will open. When I tried that with your suggested batch file, i.e. `"npp *somefiles*"`, it did open an NPP instance but did not open the files I passed. Any thoughts?

Comment: worked like a charm, as for my case I wanted to run multiple PHP versions with different aliases like php7, phpx etc. and this one worked for me

Answer (score 20):

Also, you can create an alias.cmd in your path (for example C:\Windows) with the command

```
@echo %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 > %windir%\%1.cmd
```

Once you do that, you can do something like this:

```
alias nameOfYourAlias commands to run
```

And after that you can type in comman line

```
nameOfYourAlias
```

this will execute

```
commands to run
```

BUT the best way for me is just adding the path of a programm.

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;%ProgramFiles%\Sublime Text 3" /M
```

And now I run sublime as

```
subl index.html
```

Comment: Do not use `setx` with the `PATH` variable. It can truncate your path irrecoverably.

Answer (score 15):

## Console Aliases in Windows 10

To define a console alias, use `Doskey.exe` to create a macro, or use the `AddConsoleAlias` function.

#### doskey

```
doskey test=cd \a_very_long_path\test
```

To also pass [parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/prompt.mspx?mfr=true) add `$*` at the end: `doskey short=longname $*`

#### AddConsoleAlias

```
AddConsoleAlias( TEXT("test"), 
                 TEXT("cd \\<a_very_long_path>\\test"), 
                 TEXT("cmd.exe"));
```

More information here [Console Aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057(v=vs.85).aspx), [Doskey](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx), [Parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/prompt.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: BTW, I made a new, much better answer below that allows you to register aliases for each cmd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt/59978163#59978163

Answer (score 13):

Naturally, I would not rest until I have **the most convenient solution of all**. Combining the very many answers and topics on the vast internet, here is what you can have.

- Loads automatically with every instance of `cmd`
- Doesn't require keyword `DOSKEY` for aliases
  *example: `ls=ls --color=auto $*`*

*Note that this is largely based on [Argyll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/985454) and comments, definitely read it to understand the concepts.*

[image: cmd greetings & aliases]

## How to make it work?

1. Create a `mac` macro file with the aliases
   *you can even use a `bat`/`cmd` file to also run other stuff (similar to `.bashrc` in linux)*
2. Register it in Registry to run on each instance of `cmd`
     *or run it via shortcut only if you want*

#### Example steps:

##### **`%userprofile%/cmd/aliases.mac`**

```
;==============================================================================
;= This file is registered via registry to auto load with each instance of cmd.
;================================ general info ================================
;= https://stackoverflow.com/a/59978163/985454  -  how to set it up?
;= https://gist.github.com/postcog/5c8c13f7f66330b493b8  -  example doskey macrofile
;========================= loading with cmd shortcut ==========================
;= create a shortcut with the following target :
;= %comspec% /k "(doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\cmd\aliases.mac)"

alias=echo Opening aliases in Sublime... && subl %USERPROFILE%\cmd\aliases.mac
ga=grep --color "$1" %USERPROFILE%\cmd\aliases.mac

hosts=runas /noprofile /savecred /user:QWERTY-XPS9370\administrator "subl C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" > NUL

p=@echo "~~ powercfg -devicequery wake_armed ~~" && powercfg -devicequery wake_armed && @echo "~~ powercfg -requests ~~ " && powercfg -requests && @echo "~~ powercfg -waketimers ~~"p && powercfg -waketimers

ls=ls --color=auto $*
ll=ls -l --color=auto $*
la=ls -la --color=auto $*
grep=grep --color $*

~=cd %USERPROFILE%
cdr=cd C:\repos
cde=cd C:\repos\esquire
cdd=cd C:\repos\dixons
cds=cd C:\repos\stekkie
cdu=cd C:\repos\uplus
cduo=cd C:\repos\uplus\oxbridge-fe
cdus=cd C:\repos\uplus\stratus

npx=npx --no-install $*
npxi=npx $*
npr=npm run $*

now=vercel $*


;=only in bash
;=alias whereget='_whereget() { A=$1; B=$2; shift 2; eval \"$(where $B | head -$A | tail -1)\" $@; }; _whereget'

history=doskey /history
h=IF ".$*." == ".." (echo "usage: h [ SAVE | TAIL [-|+<n>] | OPEN ]" && echo. && doskey/history) ELSE (IF /I "$1" == "OPEN" (%USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log) ELSE (IF /I "$1" == "SAVE" (echo **** %date% %time% **** >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & doskey/history >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & ECHO Command history saved) ELSE (IF /I "$1" == "TAIL" (tail $2 %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log) ELSE (doskey/history))))

;=exit=echo **** %date% %time% **** >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & doskey/history >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & ECHO Command history saved, exiting & timeout 1 & exit $*
exit=echo **** %date% %time% **** >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & doskey/history >> %USERPROFILE%\cmd\history.log & exit $*

;============================= :end ============================
;= rem ******************************************************************
;= rem * EOF - Don't remove the following line.  It clears out the ';'
;= rem * macro. We're using it because there is no support for comments
;= rem * in a DOSKEY macro file.
;= rem ******************************************************************
;=
```

Now you have three options:

- a) load manually with shortcut

  > create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` with the following target :
  > `%comspec% /k "(doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\cmd\aliases.mac)"`
- b) register just the `aliases.mac` macrofile
- c) register a regular `cmd/bat` file to also run arbitrary commands *(similar to linux's `.bashrc`)*
  *see example `cmdrc.cmd` file at the bottom*

*note: Below, `Autorun_` is just a placeholder key which will not do anything. Pick one and rename the other.*

Manually edit registry at this path:

##### **`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]`**

```
  Autorun    REG_SZ    doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\cmd\aliases.mac
  Autorun_    REG_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\cmd\cmdrc.cmd
```

Or import reg file:

##### **`%userprofile%/cmd/cmd-aliases.reg`**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\\cmd\\aliases.mac"
"Autorun_"="%USERPROFILE%\\cmd\\cmdrc.cmd"
```

##### **`%userprofile%/cmd/cmdrc.cmd`**  <sub>*you don't need this file if you decided for b) above*</sub>

```
:: This file is registered via registry to auto load with each instance of cmd.
:: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59978163/985454

@echo off
doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\cmd\aliases.mac

:: put other commands here

cls
echo Hi Qwerty, how are you today?
```

[image: cmd greetings & aliases]

Comment: Do we need the "/macrofile" - I can't find info on that.. I get "'/macrofile' is not recognized as an internal or external command"..

Comment: @Galivan It's `doskey /macrofile`

Comment: This is great, thanks 
Is there a way to use with PowerShell as well?

Comment: @UtsavBarnwal It seems that adding `/exename=powershell.exe` could make this work, like `doskey /exename=powershell.exe /macrofile=%userprofile%\cmd\aliases.mac`. But I did not test it. Then you could use this with a desktop shortcut. I bet there is a way to add it to registers too if we find the proper reg key. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-doskey-macros-to-work-in-powershell/

Comment: What sort of additions are you using for cmd? And what are you using to simulate/emulate *nix commands from cmd?

Comment: @user1023102 git for windows comes with optional unix tools (MinGW) and then I downloaded missing commands as I needed through various sites. Search UnxUtils or Gnuwin32.

Answer (score 12):

You want to create an alias by simply typing:

```
c:\>alias kgs kubectl get svc

Created alias for kgs=kubectl get svc
```

And use the alias as follows:

```
c:\>kgs alfresco-svc

NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
alfresco-svc   ClusterIP   10.7.249.219   <none>        80/TCP    8d
```

Just add the following `alias.bat` file to you path. It simply creates additional batch files in the same directory as itself.

```
  @echo off
  echo.
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ("%*") do set ALL_BUT_FIRST=%%b
  echo @echo off > C:\Development\alias-script\%1.bat
  echo echo. >> C:\Development\alias-script\%1.bat
  echo %ALL_BUT_FIRST% %%* >> C:\Development\alias-script\%1.bat
  echo Created alias for %1=%ALL_BUT_FIRST%
```

An example of the batch file this created called `kgs.bat` is:

```
@echo off 
echo. 
kubectl get svc %*
```

Comment: Note: replace above "C:\Development\alias-script\" with "%~dp0\"

Comment: Nice solution, @Steaton.  Folks should be careful that if they may be using this to run some alias command they may find (such as for Linux), that accepts an = after the aliasname, which will not work correctly here. Just remove it. (Check the resulting created bat file for your alias attempt, to confirm.)  
Also, if their path they'd name in the code above would have spaces (such as with "program files"), you'll want to put double-quotes surrounding the path and bat file name in the 3 lines above.

Comment: And to @alexbk66's helpful comment, first thanks for that nice tip for portability.  I'll add that the closing slash after his %~dp0 is not needed, as Windows will include that in its resolution of that variable (so you end up with two using your code, which might lead to a failure of the code in the created bad file, in some cases). Granted, it looks unwieldy in Steaton's code (such as "%~dp0%1.bat"), but it works. :-)

Comment: That should have been "created bat file" in my last comment. Bummer that SO doesn't permit changes to our own comments (not even 26 mins later, as I notice this).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I'll go you one better and let you in on a little technique that I've used since I used to program on an Amiga.  On *any* new system you use, be it personal or professional, step one is to create two folders:  `C:\BIN` and `C:\BATCH`.  Then modify your path statement to put both at the start in the order `C:\BATCH;C:\BIN;[rest of path]`.

Having done that, if you have little out-of-the-way utilities that you need access to simply copy them to the `C:\BIN` folder and they're in your path.  To temporarily override these assignments, you can add a batch file with the same name as the executable to the `C:\BATCH` folder and the path will find it before the file in C:\BIN.  It should cover anything you might ever need to do.

Of course, these days the canonical correct way to do this would be to create a symbolic junction to the file, but the same principle applies.  There is a little extra added bonus as well.  If you want to put something in the system that conflicts with something already in the path, putting it in the `C:\BIN` or `C:\Batch` folder will simply *pre-empt* the original - allowing you to override stuff either temporarily or permanently, or rename things to names you're more comfortable with - without actually altering the original.

Comment: This is the same answer as roryhewitt.

Comment: Actually, no it's not.  I said 'one better'.  The built-in option to override or underride an override that's already in place. The simple segregation of executables from batch files. And rory's solution does not specify *where* in the path the folder should go.  Most will therefore put it at the end of the path.  Being at the end instead of the beginning, his solution will not allow overrides in the first place.  Rory's solution is approximately the same as the solution I myself originally arrived at - 25 years ago.  I've refined the model somewhat since then.

Comment: Whatever. People using an Amiga cannot be all bad.

Comment: Fair enough :) In my case, the Aliases folder IS at the beginning of the path, but in any case, I personally don't want to override the default - my aliases always have different names. So I use 'dig2' and 'digx' as aliases to 'dig', but still have 'dig' available (without needing to specify its folder). Also +1 for Amiga :)

Comment: Nice memories , I've also renamed bat file to startup-sequence :)

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on [roryhewitt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39459404/868463) answer.

An advantage to using .cmd files over DOSKEY is that these "aliases" are then available in other shells such as PowerShell or WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux).

The only gotcha with using these commands in bash is that it may take a bit more setup since you might need to do some path manipulation before calling your "alias".

eg I have vs.cmd which is my "alias" for editing a file in Visual Studio

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto nofiles
start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /edit %1
goto end
:nofiles
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 
11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "[PATH TO MY NORMAL SLN]"
:end
```

Which fires up VS (in this case VS2012 - but adjust to taste) using my "normal" project with no file given but when given a file will attempt to attach to a running VS opening that file "within that project" rather than starting a new instance of VS.

For using this from bash I then add an extra level of indirection since "vs Myfile" wouldn't always work

```
alias vs='/usr/bin/run_visual_studio.sh'
```

Which adjusts the paths before calling the vs.cmd

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd.exe /C 'c:\Windows\System32\vs.cmd' "`wslpath.sh -w -r $1`"
```

So this way I can just do

```
vs SomeFile.txt
```

In either a command prompt, Power Shell or bash and it opens in my running Visual Studio for editing (which just saves my poor brain from having to deal with VI commands or some such when I've just been editing in VS for hours).

Answer (score 3):

Make a new folder anywhere on your system dedicated for aliases. Make a new file called whatever you want to name the alias with the `.cmd` extension. Write all commands in the file, such as

```
cd /D D:\Folder
g++ -o run something.cpp
```

Copy the folder's path.

Go to `Settings > System > About > Advanced system settings > Environment Variables...`

Now find the `Path` variable under the `System variables` section. Click on it once and click `Edit`. Now click `New` and paste the copied text.

Click `OK`, `OK` and `OK`. Restart your Powershell/cmd prompt and voila, you got your persistent alias! You can use the same folder to make other aliases too without needing to change `Path` variable again!

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not an apt one, but serves purpose in some occasions.

First create a folder and add it to your system path. Go to the executable of whatever program you want to create alias for. Right click and send to Desktop( Create Shortcut). Rename the shortcut to whatever alias name is comfortable. Now, take the shortcut and place in your folder.

From run prompt you can type the shortcut name directly and you can have the program opened for you. But from command prompt, you need to append **.lnk** and hit enter, the program will be opened.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have `notepad++.exe` in your path.  Create a shortcut in that folder named `np` and point it to `notepad++.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

My quick and dirty solution is to add a BAT file in any directory which is already in the PATH.

Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
doskey dl=aria2c --file-allocation=none $*
aria2c --file-allocation=none %**
```

So, the first time you run "dl" it will execute the bat file, but from the second time onwards it will use the alias.

Answer (score 1):

A little surprised that no one has thought of just using native file system functionality for this - creating a symbolic link.

Just run the command below in a directory of your choice that is already referenced in your PATH - `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is where I usually make them as it is added to path out-of-the-box and this is what Windows seems to be using for the OS managed execution aliases:

> mklink npp.exe "c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"

This will create a symbolic link that can be executed from both GUI and command-line-based apps and will not require additional tricks to pass parameters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could create a file named np.cmd and put it in the folder which in PATH search list.
Then, edit the np.cmd file as below:

```
@echo off
notepad++.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to **enable aliases on per-directory/per-project basis**, try the following:

1. First, create a batch file that will look for a file named `aliases` in the current directory and initialize aliases from it, let’s call it `make-aliases.cmd`

   ```
   @echo off
   if not exist aliases goto:eof
   echo [Loading aliases...]
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=^=" %%i in (aliases) do (
      echo   %%i ^<^=^> %%j
      doskey %%i=%%j
   )
   doskey aliases=doskey /macros
   echo   --------------------
   echo   aliases ^=^> list  all
   echo   alt+F10 ^=^> clear all
   echo [Done]
   ```
2. Then, create `aliases` wherever you need them using the following format:

   ```
   alias1 = command1
   alias2 = command2
   ...
   ```

   for example:

   ```
   b = nmake
   c = nmake clean
   r = nmake rebuild
   ```
3. Then, add the location of `make-aliases.cmd` to your `%PATH%` variable to make it system-wide or just keep it in a known place.
4. Make it start automatically with `cmd`.

   - I would definitely advise against using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` for this, because some development tools would trigger the autorun script multiple times per session.
   - If you use **ConEmu** you could go another way and start the script from the startup task (`Settings` > `Startup` > `Tasks`), for example, I created an entry called `{MSVC}`:

     `cmd.exe /k "vcvars64 && make-aliases"`,

     and then registered it in Explorer context menu via `Settings` > `Integration>` with `Command:` `{MSVC} -cur_console:n`, so that now I can right-click a folder and launch a VS developer prompt inside it with my `aliases` loaded automatically, if they happen to be in that folder.

     Without ConEmu, you may just want to create a shortcut to `cmd.exe` with the corresponding command or simply run `make-aliases` manually every time.

Should you happen to forget your aliases, use the `aliases` macro, and if anything goes wrong, just reset the current session by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, which is a built-in command in `cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

As `doskey` does not work for PowerShell or Windows 10 terminal apps, I am sharing this solution.

Demo to create an alias in Windows 10. Alias to be expected with input parameters:

```
com=D:\website_development\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64/php8 D:\website_development\laragon\bin\composer/composer.phar
```

Procedure:

1. Create a folder named "scripts" in the *C:* drive.
2. Inside the scripts folder, create *com.bat*
3. Open *com.bat*
4. Example for running `composer` command with specific PHP version:

   ```
   @echo off 
   set path=D:\website_development\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.2-Win32-vs16-x64/php8 D:\website_development\laragon\bin\composer/composer.phar
   set args=%*
   set command=%path% %args%
   %command%
   ```
5. Save it
6. Click "Start"
7. Search for "Edit Environment Variables"
8. Click "Advanced"
9. Add your "scripts" directory to `PATH`.

Now you can run the command as its alias.

Note: If you want to add a new alias, just create a new bat file.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean by _Windows 10 terminal apps_ in “`doskey` does not work ... [in] Windows 10 terminal apps”. `doskey` indeed works in the default command processor, `cmd.exe` hosted with`conpty.exe` inside Windows terminal `wt`. I double-checked my Windows version, which appears to be 10.0.22631.3296 (Windows 11 23H2), `doskey` works indeed, as it has always done in Windows 10 since no more than 4-6 months after its first GA release, when I first upgraded from Windows 7. But I may be misreading you indeed. For PS, the easiest equivalent is short functions in it's init file.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/). It, in turn, uses [Shim](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Shim) utility to forward commands to the corresponding executables.

So it's similar to the .cmd file solution but with the Shim's .exe file.

My goal was to run `podman.exe` by `docker` command.

So I created a copy of shim .exe file (they all are in the `%USERPROFILE%\scoop\shims` which is in the PATH) with the appropriate name (`docker.exe` in my case). Plus created a configuration file for it (`docker.shim`) with the following content:

```
path = "<USERPROFILE>\scoop\apps\podman\current\podman.exe"
```

where `<USERPROFILE>` should be replaced by the content of the `%USERPROFILE%` variable.

If you need additional parameters for the executable, it might be provided to the Shim with the `args =`  option.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the excellent answer by @roryhewitt is to use ps1 (Powershell) scripts instead, if the OP would be willing to use the Windows Terminal instead of cmd.exe. When using batch files, you will endure an irritating prompt (`Terminate batch job (Y/N)?`)whenever you need to force terminate (CTRL-C) the program that the script ran. This avoids that.

Steps 1, 2: Identical to the aforementioned answer.

Step 3:

- In the C:\Aliases folder, create a Powershell script with a filename corresponding to your desired alias. In the OP's case, `np.ps1`
- The contents of the script should simply be as follows:

  - `notepad++.exe $args`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

*As I didn’t like my command line window being blocked until I close Notepad++, this is my version of it:*

Create `np.bat` with the line:

```
@start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %*
```

This worked for me:

```
echo @start "" "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %* > np.bat
```

Move the file to `C:\Windows\System32`. (Typically requires admin privileges.)

Answer (score -1):

i have very easy way for this
suppose you want have alias  name a for php artisan command,

follow my steps:

1. create folder "my-batch-files" in path C:\Program Files\
2. creat file name a.bat in this this folder you created.
3. insert this codes inside a.bat file

php artisan %1 %2 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8

4. save file, be careful save file with .bat file not .txt
5. add folder you create for environment variable of the system,

   1. open powershell as administrator
   2. open environment variable and add path to system variable and path
6. well done, open new terminal and run a and hit enter, you see that runs php artisan

Answer (score -4):

Using doskey is the right way to do this, but it resets when the Command Prompt window is closed. You need to add that line to something like .bashrc equivalent. So I did the following:

1. Add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++" to system path variable
2. Make a copy of notepad++.exe (in the same folder, of course) and rename it to np.exe

Works just fine!