# Running npm install from Sublime Text 2 doesn't work

Tags: node.js, cmd, sublimetext2

I am trying to set up Sublime Text 2 to have a build system that runs `npm install`. My `.sublime-build` file looks like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["npm", "install"],
    "shell": true
}
```

However, when I try to build, I get the following error:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I also get a series of similar messages about `doskey`, likely originating from a batch file that I have set to run when `cmd.exe` is started (as demonstrated in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040825/2789699)).

What is causing this problem? I'm not welded to this solution - I'm open to anything that will allow me to run `npm install` from ST2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my `PATH` wasn't updating correctly. I don't know if this is actually what was causing the issue or not, but simply restarting Sublime Text has fixed it.