# IOError when running scons.bat

Tags: python, scons, ioerror

When I run my scons, I get the following IOError and also that it cannot find path specified. I checked that my Path is corerctly pointing to my Python in Windows path. I am running in Win7.

```
C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
The system cannot find the path specified.
IOError: The system cannot find the path specified.
:
  File "C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE\SConstruct", line 55:
    ''')
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 612:
    env = self.factory()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 592:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Defaults.py", line 88:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 1003:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 1811:
    tool(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\default.py", line 41:
    SCons.Tool.Tool(t)(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\mslink.py", line 303:
    msvc_setup_env_once(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 374:
    msvc_setup_env(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 481:
    d = msvc_find_valid_batch_script(env,version)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 431:
    d = script_env(vc_script, args=arg)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 320:
    stdout = common.get_output(script, args)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\common.py", line 193:
    raise IOError(stderr.decode("mbcs"))
```

Any idea what has gone wrong here?

My Scons and Python versions plus my environment variables are:

```
C:\>echo %PATH%
C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Users\SESAxxxxx\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit
_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\libexec\git-core;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Klocwork\Insight 10.0 Command Line\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\bin;C:\Pro
gram Files (x86)\Common Files\Gtk\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\QT Lite\QTSystem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Box\Box Edit\
;C:\Program Files (x86)\1E\NomadBranch\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AccuRev\bin;C:\qnx660\host\win32\x86\usr\bin;C:\qnx660\.qnx\bin;C:\qnx660\jre\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\7-
Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\node
js\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Produc
tivity Tools;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC;C:\myrepopath\Softwar eTools\beautify\Software\Utilities\beautify;C:\Users\SESAxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>echo %HOME%
c:\users\SESAxxxxx\Documents

C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
        script: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
        engine: v2.3.4, 2014/09/27 12:51:43, by garyo on lubuntu
        engine path: ['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\..\\Lib\\site-packages\\scons-2.3.4\\SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2014 The SCons Foundation

C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>python --version
Python 2.7.5

C:\>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

I also turn on Scons debugger:

```
set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=-
```

Then running scons again I see this:

```
C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.bat
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
trying to find VC 12.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\12.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 12.0
trying to find VC 12.0Exp
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VCExpress\\12.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 12.0Exp
trying to find VC 11.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\11.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 11.0
trying to find VC 11.0Exp
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VCExpress\\11.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 11.0Exp
trying to find VC 10.0
find_vc_dir(): found VC in registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
found VC 10.0
trying to find VC 10.0Exp
find_vc_dir(): found VC in registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
found VC 10.0Exp
trying to find VC 9.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\9.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 9.0
trying to find VC 9.0Exp
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VCExpress\\9.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 9.0Exp
trying to find VC 8.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\8.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 8.0
trying to find VC 8.0Exp
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VCExpress\\8.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 8.0Exp
trying to find VC 7.1
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\7.1\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 7.1
trying to find VC 7.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\7.0\\Setup\\VC\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 7.0
trying to find VC 6.0
find_vc_dir(): no VC registry key 'Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\6.0\\Setup\\Microsoft Visual C++\\ProductDir'
find_vc_pdir return None for ver 6.0
msvc_setup_env()
get_default_version()
get_default_version(): msvc_version:None msvs_version:None
installed_vcs:['10.0', '10.0Exp']
msvc_setup_env: using default installed MSVC version '10.0'

msvc_setup_env: using specified MSVC version '10.0'

vc.py:msvc_find_valid_batch_script()
vc.py:get_host_target()
vc.py:get_host_target() req_target_platform:None
msvs_find_valid_batch_script(): req_target_platform None target_platform:amd64
msvs_find_valid_batch_script(): host_platform: amd64 try_target_archs:['amd64', 'x86_amd64', 'x86']
vc.py:msvc_find_valid_batch_script() trying target_platform:amd64
find_vc_dir(): found VC in registry: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
vc.py: find_batch_file() pdir:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
sdk.py:get_installed_sdks()
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 7.0
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\InstallationFolder
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0\\InstallationFolder'
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 6.1
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\InstallationFolder
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.1\\InstallationFolder'
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 6.0A
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\InstallationFolder
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\InstallationFolder'
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 6.0
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\InstallationFolder
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0\\InstallationFolder'
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 2003R2
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\MicrosoftSDK\InstalledSDKS\D2FF9F89-8AA2-4373-8A31-C838BF4DBBE1\Install Dir
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\MicrosoftSDK\\InstalledSDKS\\D2FF9F89-8AA2-4373-8A31-C838BF4DBBE1\\Install Dir'
MSCommon/sdk.py: trying to find SDK 2003R1
find_sdk_dir(): checking registry:Software\Microsoft\MicrosoftSDK\InstalledSDKS\8F9E5EF3-A9A5-491B-A889-C58EFFECE8B3\Install Dir
find_sdk_dir(): no SDK registry key 'Software\\Microsoft\\MicrosoftSDK\\InstalledSDKS\\8F9E5EF3-A9A5-491B-A889-C58EFFECE8B3\\Install Dir'
vc.py:msvc_find_valid_batch_script() vc_script:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat sdk_script:None
vc.py:msvc_find_valid_batch_script() use_script 2 u'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat', args:amd64

PATH: C:\Windows\System32
Calling 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat amd64'
The system cannot find the path specified.
IOError: The system cannot find the path specified.
:
  File "C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE\SConstruct", line 55:
    ''')
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 612:
    env = self.factory()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Script\SConscript.py", line 592:
    default_env = SCons.Defaults.DefaultEnvironment()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Defaults.py", line 88:
    _default_env = SCons.Environment.Environment(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 1003:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Environment.py", line 1811:
    tool(self)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\default.py", line 41:
    SCons.Tool.Tool(t)(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\__init__.py", line 183:
    self.generate(env, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\mslink.py", line 303:
    msvc_setup_env_once(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 374:
    msvc_setup_env(env)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 481:
    d = msvc_find_valid_batch_script(env,version)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 431:
    d = script_env(vc_script, args=arg)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\vc.py", line 320:
    stdout = common.get_output(script, args)
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\..\Lib\site-packages\scons-2.3.4\SCons\Tool\MSCommon\common.py", line 193:
    raise IOError(stderr.decode("mbcs"))

C:\myrepopath\PROJECT_FILE>
```

Here is my Sconstruct snippet:

```
    ###############################################################################
#                           Included Modules                                  #
###############################################################################

import os
#from glob import glob
#from os.path import basename, splitext, exists, isdir, join, normcase
#from os import chmod
import re
import sys
import XanTools
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


###############################################################################
#                           Constant Data                                     #
###############################################################################

PROD_INFO_FILE = 'DOC/prod_info.xml'

###############################################################################
#                      Utility  functions                                     #
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#               The main build script starts here                             #
###############################################################################

Help('''SCons build for x Board

x
x
x

x
x

x
x
x
x
x
x

x
x

x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x - x shared library for x simulator
''')
#def MyGlob(pattern, ondisk=True, source=True, strings=False, recursive=False):
#    """ Recursive glob function """

#    dirname = os.path.dirname(pattern)
#    pattern = os.path.basename(pattern)
#    names = Glob(os.path.join(dirname, pattern), ondisk, source, strings)

#    if recursive :

#        for entry in Glob(os.path.join(dirname, '*'), source=True, strings=False):

#            if entry.__class__ is SCons.Node.FS.Dir :
#                names += MyGlob(os.path.join(str(entry), pattern), ondisk, source, strings, recursive)

#    return names

# Function to generat uEnv.txt files based on IFS file name
def fnGenUEnvTxt(target, source, env):
    filename = str(target[0])
    print 'Generating %s' % filename

    # Use binary mode to force UNIX line endings
    outfp = open(filename, 'wb')

    outfp.write( """# x
addr=x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

# x
x

""" % ( os.path.basename( str( source[ 0 ] ) ) ) )
    outfp.close()

# Command line option to build a debug version (Release is the default)
AddOption('--variant',
          dest='variant',
          default='release',
          help='Build a selected variant (debug or release)')
variant = GetOption('variant')

# Supported platforms are win32, posix, linux_am335x_evm and qnx_am335x.
# SE1 system board support will come later
AddOption('--platform',
          dest='platform',
          default=None,
          help="CPU platform to build on")
platform = GetOption('platform')

# Specify a project for QNX debug configurations
AddOption('--debug_project',
          dest='debug_project',
          help='Project name to attach to debug configurations')
debug_project = GetOption('debug_project')

# Specify a host for debug configurations
AddOption('--debug_host',
          dest='debug_host',
          help='Host name for debugging on target board')
debug_host = GetOption('debug_host')

# Specify to build BSP first, necessary when BSP has never been built
AddOption( '--bsp_first',
           dest='bsp_first',
           help='Build BSP first')
bsp_first = GetOption('bsp_first')

AddOption( '--build_web',
           dest='build_web',
           help='web build')
build_web = GetOption('build_web')

# Specify to build AFS (encrypted IFS)
AddOption( '--build_afs',
           dest='afs',
           help='Build AFS')
afs = GetOption('afs')

# Specify to regenerate config files based on ICB artifacts
AddOption( '--icbconfig',
           dest='icbconfig',
           help='Gen ICB XML files')
icbconfig = GetOption('icbconfig')

# Get the default environment for all x products, customized from
# the product info file
env = XanTools.fnDefaultEnvironment(PROD_INFO_FILE)
env['VARIANT'] = variant

if platform is not None:
    env['PLATFORM'] = platform

# Override variant for win32 platform is always debug
if env['PLATFORM'] in ['win32', 'posix', 'qnx_x86']:
    env['VARIANT'] = 'debug'

# Command line debug options
if debug_project is not None:
    env['DEBUG_PROJECT'] = debug_project

if debug_host is not None:
    env['DEBUG_HOST'] = debug_host

if env['PLATFORM'] == 'qnx_am335x_bbb':  
    bsp_dir = 'Software/Code/OS/bsp/Src/'
    sconscript_file = bsp_dir + 'SConscript'

elif env['PLATFORM'] == 'qnx_am335x_evm':
    bsp_dir = 'Software/Code/OS/QNX/bsp-nto650-ti-am335x-evm/'
    sconscript_file = bsp_dir + 'SConscript'

else:
    bsp_dir = None
    sconscript_file = None

# Additional includes if building to a specific BSP
if bsp_dir is not None:
    env['BSPPATH'] = ['#' + bsp_dir + 'prebuilt/usr/include',
                      '#' + bsp_dir + 'src/hardware/startup/lib/public']

# Can build the bootloader only for QNX targets from a Linux host
if env['PLATFORM'].startswith('qnx') and (sys.platform != 'win32'):
    # Build boot loader
    bootloader = env.SConscript( 'Software/Code/BootLoader/u-boot/SConscript',
                                 exports='env' )
else:
    # The boot loader currently cannot be built under Windows
    bootloader = []


# Build the processes and libraries
variant_binaries, shared_libraries, buildenv = env.SConscript('Software/Code/SConscript',
                                                              variant_dir='${PLATFORM}_${VARIANT}',
                                                              duplicate=0,
                                                              exports='env')

variant_binaries += bootloader

# Build the above software into an image file system
if sconscript_file is not None:
    env.Tool('qnx', platform=env['PLATFORM'], variant=env['VARIANT'])
    bsp = env.SConscript(sconscript_file,
                         variant_dir='Software/Build/bspifs',
                         duplicate=1,
                         exports='env')
else:
    bsp = variant_binaries[0:1]

if (bsp_first is None) and (env['PLATFORM'].startswith('qnx')):

    if (build_web is not None):
        env.SConscript('Software/Code/Web/SConscript', exports='env' )

    ifsfile = env.SConscript('Software/Config/SConscript',
                             exports='env bsp variant_binaries shared_libraries')    

    if sys.platform == "win32":
        binaries = [ ifsfile[ 0 ], File( bsp_dir + 'images/MLO' ), File( bsp_dir + 'images/u-boot.img' ) ]
    else:
        Depends( ifsfile, bootloader )
        binaries = [ ifsfile[ 0 ], bootloader[ 0 ], bootloader[ 1 ] ]


    # Copy the binaries to the top level, renaming the first to the part number
    # with the same file extension as before
    target_binaries = []
    for i, src in enumerate(binaries):
        if i == 0:
            new_file_name = env['PART_NUMBER'] + os.path.splitext(str(src))[1]
        else:
            new_file_name = os.path.basename(str(src))

        target_binaries += Command(new_file_name,
                                   str( src ),
                                   [ 
                                     Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
                                     Chmod('$TARGET', 0777), 
                                   ])

    Depends( target_binaries, ifsfile )

    env['BINARY'] = target_binaries[0]

    def EncryptFile( target, source, env ):
        # generate random initialization vector 
        iv = os.urandom(16)
#        print 'IV: ' + iv.encode('hex')

        keyList = [ 0x3c, 0x21, 0x6a, 0x37, 0xba, 0xca, 0xfd, 0x91, 0xff, 0x49, 0x22, 0x28, 0x58, 0x3b, 0xeb, 0xf5 ]
        key = "".join( chr( i ) for i in keyList )
#        print [('%02X' % ord(i)) for i in key]

        aes = AES.new( key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv )

        infp = open( str( source[ 0 ] ), 'rb' )
        data_in = infp.read()
        infp.close()
#        print "*** Read " + str( len( data_in ) ) + " bytes"
#        print "*** Block size = " + str( AES.block_size )
#        print "*** Blocks = " + str( len( data_in ) / AES.block_size )
#        print "*** Left over bytes = " + str( len( data_in ) % AES.block_size )
        data_in += " " * ( AES.block_size -  len( data_in ) % AES.block_size )

        data_out = aes.encrypt( data_in )
        outfp = open( str( target[ 0 ] ), 'wb' )
        # store IV as first 16 bytes before ciphertext
        outfp.write( iv )
        outfp.write( data_out )
        outfp.close()

    if afs is not None:
        afs_file = env.Command( os.path.splitext( os.path.basename( str( target_binaries[ 0 ] ) ) )[ 0 ] + ".afs",
                            target_binaries[ 0 ],
                            EncryptFile )
        Depends( afs_file, ifsfile )
        target_binaries[0] = afs_file

    # Add in uEnv.txt which needs to know the name of the first binary
    target_binaries += env.Command('uEnv.txt',
                                   target_binaries[0],
                                   fnGenUEnvTxt)
else:
    target_binaries = []

    env['BINARY'] = ','.join([str(file) for file in target_binaries])


print 'variant binaries: ', variant_binaries
print 'target binaries: ', target_binaries

if icbconfig is not None:
    # Support for regenerating config files based on ICB artifacts
    sysdef = env.Command("Software/Utilities/Config/x.xml",
                      ["Software/Utilities/Config/x.xml", 
                       "Software/Utilities/Config/x.xml",
                       "Software/Utilities/Config/x.py"],
                       "python x.py", chdir=1)
    Depends(ifsfile, sysdef)

# Add support for the auto-incrementing build number
XanTools.fnBuildNumberSupport(env)

# Support for the Software Version PDF and the bundled zip files
XanTools.fnBundleSupport(env, PROD_INFO_FILE, target_binaries)

# Support for running unit tests
try:
     del(buildenv['PDB'])
except KeyError:
     pass
testlib, testenv = buildenv.SConscript('Software/Code/libs/CppUTest/SConscript',
                                       exports='buildenv')


# Print out the program environment (for QNX builds)
print "\nProgram environment:"
envkeys = os.environ.keys()
envkeys.sort()
for key in envkeys:
    print "%s : %s" % (key, os.environ[key])

print "\n"
env.Alias( 'bsp', [bsp, variant_binaries, shared_libraries] )
```

Comment: I think more info is needed to know which path scons is referring to. Where does this `scons.bat` file come from? Are you trying to install something using scons? If so, what?

Comment: @Evert I am trying to build my ifs using scons. Scons is similar to makefiles for building images. But I see it a bit more complicated. Anyways, when installing scons, it will put scons.bat in _C:\Python27\Scripts\scons.bat_

Comment: @Evert Provided more info by setting SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=- and running again, you can see the results above. I have no clue why this is happening. Everything is there!

Comment: Can you please post your SConstruct file? The error message seems to point at a problem with a filename that you specified... See the ''') part? Have you added a line break before that line, which gets added to the string for the filename then?

Comment: @dirkbaechle linebreak is not the problem. Please look at my Sconstruct above. The problem is coming from "cannot find the path specified". And I do not know why? Additionally, I guess the errors are read from last to first. So the last error is to fix first?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved once I removed my alias key (my alias batch file containing doskeys) in regedit. I followed instructions from [stackoverflow aliases in windoes, look at the third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt). But it resulted in crashing my scons build!

I never knew **regedit** can be damaged by adding an autorun key to it! Windows is behaving like Linux in no way and I am a Linux guy and have to suffer using Windows for a while!