# Opening sublime from gitbash (subl . -a &)

Tags: windows, git-bash

this is my first stackoverflow post, so apologies if I don't adhere to forum standards.

I'm using gitbash on windows. I wanted to be able to open sublime 3 from gitbash terminal, so I followed these instructions https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/sublime.

However, subl . opened two instances of sublime and did not run sublime in the background (So I couldn't use terminal anymore).

The only solution I found to this is to type subl . -a & into terminal. -a prevents two instances of sublime from being opened and & allows sublime to run in the background, so I can continue using terminal.

Is there anyway I can type subl . to perform the same function as subl . -a &?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for that command. Not sure how to create aliases on windows but try looking into this
[Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: thank you, I'll research that more. I currently have this in my .bashrc file: alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"

Comment: try creating another alias with sub="subl . -a &"

Comment: that doesn't work for some reason. So my file looks like this
alias subl="C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/sublime_text.exe"
alias sub="subl . -a &" 

but subl. creates two windows and doesn't run in the background