# Running both Python 2.7 and 3.5 on PC

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both versions of Python installed on my PC running Windows 10 and I can switch between them manually as needed, but I was wondering if there is a way to edit their path environment variables so that I can launch both of them from the CMD easily.

For example, instead of typing "python" to launch whatever is the default one right now, I want to just type python2 for one, and python3 for the other, is that possible?

**Update**: it turned out that you don't need any trick for this, you just use either `py -2` or `py -3` accordingly. Alternatively, you can configure your own aliases in `cmd` as mentioned below.

Comment: You could just create copies of both `python.exe`s and name them `python2.exe` and `python3.exe`.

Comment: A simple solution would be to go to the directories where they're installed and copy `python.exe` to `pythonX.exe`, where X is whatever suffix you want, and then put both directories in your PATH.

Comment: I considered that already but I thought that this method might cause other problems somewhere else, after a second thought I guess it won't. Thank you!

Comment: Can't you use `py -2` and `py -3`?

Comment: I wasn't even aware that this exists! Thank you @ValentinLorentz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has more to do with Windows and less to do with Python IMO. You might want to take a look at [Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt) 
You should be able to use

```
DOSKEY python3=C:\path\to\python3.exe $*
DOSKEY python2=C:\path\to\python2.exe $*
```

to define the alias. You can then put those in a `.cmd` file e.g. `env.cmd` and use

```
cmd.exe /K env.cmd
```

to automatically load the aliases into the shell when you run it.
That's the way I would go about doing this. I hope it helps.

Comment: This is what I needed exactly, Thanks.

Comment: Windows console aliases are very limited. They're not real commands. You can't use them in scripts or batch files. You can't even pipe to them. They're just a simple text replacement matched at the beginning of a line of input that's read from the console (conhost.exe). One useful thing about them is that you can load a different set of aliases for each program that's attached to the console (e.g. cmd.exe, powershell.exe, cdb.exe, or python.exe). This is most conveniently accomplished using the `/macrofile` option of [doskey.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753867).

Comment: For an actual command, other than using py.exe, you can use `mklink` to create a hard or symbolic link to python.exe. You could also create a .lnk shell shortcut to python.exe. Clear its "start in" field to inherit the working directory of the command prompt, and add .LNK to the `PATHEXT` environment variable to avoid having to type the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) or [`cygwin`](https://www.cygwin.com/). Using the later you can have both versions python installed and invoked as you from the same terminal.

Another possible alternative might be [Ubuntu on Windows](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/) but personally I have not tried this.

If your are looking for a native solution to use in `Windows Command Prompt` or `Power Shell`, as mentioned by [Paradoxinabox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510412/paradoxinabox) you have to go with aliases.

Comment: I am waiting for the anniversary update to try Ubuntu on a final build of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied two batch files from WinPython distribution,

*cmd.bat*

```
@echo off
call %~dp0env.bat
cmd.exe /k
```

and *env.bat* (edited)

```
@echo off
set WINPYDIR=C:\devel\Python34
set PATH=%WINPYDIR%\;%WINPYDIR%\DLLs;%WINPYDIR%\Scripts;%PATH%;
```

where `WINPYDIR` corresponds to the install path. I have placed these to *Scripts* subdirectory (for example *C:\devel\Python34\Scripts*), and then a suitable shortcut on desktop that launches command prompt with `PATH` variable set.