# Installation of Octave via the Zip file

Tags: windows, octave

I downloaded the octave 5.1.0 zip file, 64 bits for Windows. After extraction, I was only able to get access to the GUI. Any help on how I can access the CLI?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357770/128511

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command (that you can put into a starter or bat-file):

`"C:\path_to_your_dir\Octave\octave.vbs" --force-gui`