# Execute jar file without "java -jar" (like a command)

Tags: java, cmd, jar

is possible to shortcut :
`java -jar myscript.jar` to `myscript`.

Like a real command, is possible in Linux (by moving file in specific directory) but is it possible in Windows ?

Thanks !

Comment: create a `bat` file which executes the full command and add it to the `PATH`.

Comment: Great idea, but what i add to the path ?

Comment: The folder where the file is placed. Or, if you want, you can place the file into the `System32` directory (which should already be part of the `PATH`). But I would not place files inside the `System32` folder, I think that the "clean way" is to create your folder and add it to the `PATH`.

Comment: try
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: Nice! I'll try, thanks, BackSlash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows and linux have aliases, in the windows you can call "calc" or "cmd" from 
anywhere.

So, try read this topics:

- [Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)
- http://www.displayobject.fr/2010/03/07/create-cmd-aliases-in-windows/