# How do I make a command line interface with a custom command?

Tags: java, command-line-interface

I am making an application with java, and I don't know how to make a custom command in java.

So, basically, I would like a command like

```
myjavaapp [arguments]
```

instead of

```
java -jar [jar] [arguments]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: No generic way, OS-dependent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704101/execute-jar-file-without-java-jar-like-a-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute jar file without "java -jar" (like a command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704101/execute-jar-file-without-java-jar-like-a-command)

Comment: The `jlink` command, which is part of the JDK, will do this for you, if you use its `--launcher` option.