# How can I trick bash to think I ran a script from within the directory where the binary is located?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, path, android-sdk-tools

I have a binary (`emulator` from the `Android SDK Tools`) that I use frequently. I've added it to my `$PATH` variable so that I can easily run the command with solely `emulator`.

However, it turns out that the binary uses relative paths; it complains if I run the script from a different directory. I'd really like to run the command from any folder without having to `cd` into the directory where the binary lives. Is there any way to get the script/bash into thinking I ran the command from the directory that it's located in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is an appropriate tool for the job:

```
emu() ( cd /dir/with/emulator && exec ./emulator "$@" )
```

Let's break this down into pieces:

- Using a function rather than an alias allows arguments to be substituted at an arbitrary location, rather than only at the end of the string an alias defines. That's critical, in this case, because we want the arguments to be evaluated *inside* a subshell, as described below:
- Using parentheses, instead of curly brackets, causes this function's body to run in a subshell; that ensures that the `cd` only takes effect for that subshell, and doesn't impact the parent.
- Using `&&` to connect the `cd` and the following command ensures that we abort correctly if the `cd` fails.
- Using `exec` tells the subshell to replace itself in memory with the emulator, rather than having an extra shell sitting around that does nothing but wait for the emulator to exit.
- `"$@"` expands to the list of arguments passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias (emu) to your ~/.bashrc:

```
alias emu="(cd /dir/with/emulator; ./emulator)"
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, both proposals are useful. Thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy & Cyrus - having command-line arguments go through is crucial for this. CharlesDuffy - your solution works great. If either this answer is updated or a new answer is submitted, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into command line aliases.

If you are in linux and using bash you can go to ~/.bash_profile and add a line such as:

```
alias emulator='./path-to-binary/emulator"
```

On windows it's a little different. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt) is an example on how to do a similar thing in windows.

Comment: The alias proposed here doesn't change the working directory.

Comment: (...and part of the reason aliases are a questionable tool choice here is that it's tricky to make one that *does* change the working directory while scoping that change to only one command, and which also passes through command-line arguments, without also defining a function and just making the alias a wrapper for the function... at which point, why use an alias at all, rather than having a function do 100% of the work?)