# Any way to access a specific directory without entire directory name?

Tags: command-prompt, cd

I don't use the command line often, only for executing Python files. When I do, I find it a hassle to have to find and write out the entire directory name (For example, `C:\Users\John\Desktop\...`) Is there any way to simply use the command prompt to get into a directory (such as `C:\Users\`) and then go down a single directory into the file of choice, like `C:\Users\John`?

Comment: If you press Tab, it will auto-complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an alias that allows you to quickly access whatever directory you are commonly operating in... I don't have time to post an example right now but here's another post that should be able to nudge you in the right direction, if it doesn't fully answer your question

[Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

You can also navigate to where you want to be in the GUI file explorer, type cmd in the navbar and hit enter, the command line will open at the current directory.

Example

[image]