# How can I create Windows shortcut commands for git?

Tags: git, cmd, alias

Having to type `git commit -m "Message"` all the time has become tiresome, so I started looking up how to create shortcut commands for git.
I found out you can create git aliases with `git config --global alias.cm 'commit -m'`, but I'd still have to do `git cm "Message"`. I want to go even shorter.
After more looking I found out you can create windows shortcuts with the `doskey` command, but from what I can tell it just creates a shortcut command for an application in the PATH.

How can I create a Windows command so that I can type `gcm "Message"` and have it behave as if I typed `git commit -m "Message"`?

**Edit:**
My question is similar to [Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt), however, it is different in that I want parameters to be supplied with the shortcut command automatically. The solution in that post requires you to enter all parameters manually, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What operating system are you on? And what IDE are you using?

Comment: @user1767754 Windows 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aliases in windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: @lucidbrot That's the post I looked at where I learned about the `doskey` command, but as I stated in my question it looks like it's just a way to create a shortcut for a command in the PATH. From what I see, you'd need to supply parameters to the shortcut every time you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not try making the doskey permanent, but I just tried the following and it worked:

```
git init
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
```

to prepare my repo

```
doskey gc=git commit -m $*
```

to prepare the alias

now `gc` tells me that "switch m requires a value". To commit, it is now `gc "testmessage"`

I will edit why the `$*` works as soon as I know. I just remembered this from somewhere.

Similarly, you can use

```
doskey gcm=git commit -m "Message"
```

and then typing `gcm` will be that exact equivalent, always including "Message"

Edit: The `$*` was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt), but I just tried and it seems like `%*` would work as well to catch all arguments. I'm still not sure what the difference between the two is, but it seems like `$*` works in the cmd and from a batch file, while `%*` only works from the cmd. Source is trying out - I couldn't find anything about this yet.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't think that would work because of me overthinking things as usual. Thank you for the help.