# How to define a DOSKEY alias for multiple commands?

Tags: windows, command-line, alias, doskey

Following on from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)

For the Windows command prompt I can define aliases as follows:

```
@echo off
DOSKEY ns=npm start
DOSKEY nsr=npm run serve
```

I want to define an alias that will combine these two commands.  I tried the following:

```
@echo off
DOSKEY nss=npm start && npm run serve
```

When I try to open the command prompt the window will open but the `>` prompt does not appear.

I think that the inclusion of `&&` is causing a problem.

Comment: **See Also**: [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20530996/1366033)

Comment: see alse https://superuser.com/a/1349294/965349

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I looked at an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/715702) to a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/62850/execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-windows-commandline) on superuser.  The following approach resolved my problem:

```
@echo off
DOSKEY nss=npm start ^&^& npm run serve
```

Comment: I hope you realize that this is just a substitution rule in the console via [`AddConsoleAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/addconsolealias). It does the substitution in the input buffer, before a console client program (e.g. cmd.exe) even reads a line of input. These aliases only work at the start of a line entered in the console (i.e. you can't pipe to them) and not in batch scripts. For doskey.exe, you can use `$T$T` in place of `&&`, which is more flexible then using `^` to escape the `&` operator in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm not aware of any need to pipe to these commands at the moment.

Answer (score 34):

The command separator for DOSKEY is `$T`

For your example:

```
DOSKEY nss=npm start $T npm run serve
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I tried this and the `>` prompt would appear.  I encountered a different problem after that.  If the first command failed for some reason then the second command would still execute.  I opted for a different approach which I will post.

Comment: Add another `$T` to form `&&`, and this will be the best answer.

Comment: `DOSKEY nss=npm start $T$T npm run serve` - works perfectly! From microsoft docs using $T is preferred method. [doskeys via Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey#remarks)

Answer (score 4):

My approach is to load the macros from a text file:

```
a.bat:
    @doskey /macrofile=C:\%HOMEPATH%\bin\aliases.txt
```

and in the macro file, && works:

```
aliases.txt:
    cl=cd /d $* && dir
```

Then if I type "cl bin" from HOMEPATH, it does "cd /d bin" and then "dir":

```
C:\Users\mike> cl bin
09/17/2020  09:27 AM             1,303 a.bat
09/30/2020  03:17 PM               886 aliases.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it as a batch file and then calling the batch file use the DOSKEY command

```
REM do_npm.bat
npm start
npm run serve
```

Then, run the DOSKEY command

```
DOSKEY npm=do_npm.bat
```

See if that works for you

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I've opted for a different approach though as I want to avoid additional files.