# Why does running phpunit with Laravel return "no tests executed"?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I recently downloaded a fresh setup of Laravel 5.7 and have tried running the `phpunit` command at the command prompt with the basic settings, but it always comes through with "No tests executed"

[image: command prompt response]

Yet it has default tests that should run.
Below is the snapshot of the folder setup and  `phpunit.xml`.

[image: folder setup and phpunit.xml]

What am I missing?

I am running the setup on xampp v3.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your command line it seems as you used very old PhpUnit so probably you use globally installed PhpUnit. Instead you should rather run

```
vendor\bin\phpunit.bat
```

to run PhpUnit that is installed for current project and it should use phpunit.xml without any problem

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. It worked like a charm. 
Is there a way to have the original arrangement work? Do I always have to use

`vendor\bin\phpunit.bat`

Comment: @SamsonRwakabuguli You can probably create some alias using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt