# How to Create Command-Line Commands for a C# Program

Tags: c#, shell, command-line

I wish to make a command-line file searching program in C#. I want it to have a callable name such as 'search' as well as command-line arguments such as 'search name'. How might one implement this in C#?
I figure I will have to create a new command line command, but I don't know how parameters might be passed to C# methods.

Comment: There are several good nuget packages out there for parsing command line arguments. Regardless, you need to be more specific about the issue you are encountering.

Comment: I thought I was pretty specific. Callable name, passable commands.

Comment: Or, as an off-the-wall alternative, you could create one (or a set of) PowerShell _Cmdlets_ in a "module".  Powershell handles aliases, command completion, intelligent "pipelining", etc. much better than cmd.exe.

Comment: A sample usage? Sample code? "How to use command line arguments to do an unspecified thing" is fairly broad. Apparently you were just looking for the `args` array, I assumed you had at least gotten that far.

Comment: That wasn't all. I mentioned how one would make a cmd/PowerShell command to execute with those arguments. As crazy as it might sound, they never really taught me the full meaning of public static void Main(String[] args), and the internet doesn't directly either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters passed from consoles can be accessed if the Main method has parameter `string[] args`. Alternatively, this can be accessed using the method `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`. Unlike C/C++, this does not include the name of the program.

Here is a question on adding aliases: [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt) This would enable you to type 'search' instead of search.exe.

Comment: So if I entered the alias followed by a string, that string would be passed into the args[] array?

Comment: @EpicNicks Say, if you typed "search.exe FileName -a -b" into the cmd, `args` would be { "FileName", "-a", "-b"}.

Comment: About to try it. Didn't know that was even a thing. Cool. Here's a digital gold star.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging you can set command line arguments in the project properties.

[image]

Then simply access the arg parameter in the main event (for a console app).

[image]