# Select the python interpreter between 32 and 64 bit in windows CMD

Tags: python

I know we can use python 2 and python 3 by calling py -2 and py -3, respectively, in machines where both python 2 and python 3 are installed.
I have installed both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Python 3.7.2. Is there a way to choose between these two versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full path to your python executable,

make a permanent alias ([tricky on windows but doable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)) to it

or edit your PATH accordingly,

you can also use a [python environment manager](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) like `pipenv`.

There isn't to my knowledge a built in way to do this.

Comment: How can I make an alias in windows?

Comment: Thanks, dear @Benoît Pilatte