# How do I create an alias for Windows command line using Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to create an alias for running a Java program - `java -jar {app}\exec\myprog.jar`

How do I create it?

Comment: What *alias* do you mean?

Comment: UNIX Aliasing. Is the option available in Windows? (looks like I can). 
How do I set it? if I say `tool`, it must run `java -jar {app}\exec\myprog.jar`

Comment: I believe that only Windows 10 Store application support aliases. --- If you are in doubt, ask a generic (not Inno Setup) Windows questions on aliases on [su]. If you get an answer, we can then help you implement that in Inno Setup. --- Of course, you can create a Windows batch file, as a kind of alias.

Comment: See also [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20530996/850848)