# How can i create own alias for "php artisan" command on windows?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6.2

I have seen the documentation for creating own alias but its little confusing.
can anyone help me and simply say me what to do? 
I think it will help a lot of people, because i saw few questions related to this on stackoverflow but it really hard to get. Thank you.

Comment: rename the artisan file in your project folder to "art" then "php art"

Answer (score 10):

If you can use git bash:

- Open `bash.bashrc` (usually found at => `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`)
- Create your alias (Example => `alias art='php artisan'` )
- Save and Exit

Answer (score 6):

There is another way for **Windows** users. I want to set `pa` for `php artisan`

**Step 1) Create *pa.bat* file**

First I create a folder for example `C:\Aliases` and create a file called `pa.bat` inside that folder. Then, I need to write following lines inside `C:\Aliases\pa.bat`

```
@echo off
echo.
php artisan %*
```

**Step 2) Edit PATH environment variable**

And I also need to add `C:\Aliases` in my PATH environment variable.
To do so, just search "edit env" and you will find "*Edit environment variables for your account*", then click on "*Path*", then "*Edit*", then add ***C:\Aliases*** to the list.

**Step 3) Use the alias**

Now, just close terminal and open it again. And now you can just use `pa` instead of `php artisan`. For example :

```
pa serve --port=8800
pa make:controller
pa migrate:fresh
```

This way, you can set alias for any command in windows. If you like to see more ways to set aliases in Windows, you can check out this question in stackoverflow:
[Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)

Comment: general and easy. Nice