# Why %cd% set in doskey alias script returns script path instead of the current directory

Tags: batch-file, directory, doskey

I am setting an alias file in %userprofile%\alias.cmd containing basic DOSKEY cmd:

```
@echo off
DOSKEY ls=dir
DOSKEY clear=cls
DOSKEY pwd=echo %cd%
```

*I am installing alias.cmd in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor, such as described in [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt)*

And test:

```
C:\Users\tim>cd workspace

C:\Users\tim\workspace>pwd
C:\Users\tim

C:\Users\tim\workspace>echo %cd%
C:\Users\tim\workspace
```

I am wondering why %cd% returns script path instead of the current directory 
doskey `pwd` should have the same result than `echo %cd%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the line:

```
DOSKEY pwd=echo %cd%
```

is inside a batch script, there the `%cd%` will be evaluated at the time of your definition of the macro.
You set your `pwd`-macro with a fixed value.

Try to use:

```
DOSKEY pwd=echo %%cd%%
```