# How to shorten Java -jar command in windows terminal

Tags: command-line, jar

Is there a way to set a jar to behave like a regular batch file in windows, meaning that i only have to type `MyJar param1 param2` instead of `java -jar MyJar.jar param1 param2` ? I am looking for a global solution that i only have to setup once, not a Jar Specific solution such as creating a batch file for every jar i wish to run.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking to create an alias. This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt

Comment: thanks! though it seems from a quick look that that will still require a command before the name of the jar for instance if i make `jj` an alias for `java -jar` istill have to type it before the jar filename. im looking for something more like i noted in my question

Comment: You could set the alias to include a file name or even your parameters. For example: DOSKEY jj=java -jar path-to-my-jar\MyJar.jar

Comment: @alon gadot. toda. it will still be a jar specific solution, meaning ill need a separate alias for each jar, or ill need to preface each jar with the alias. there must be a way to just have cmd learn how to handle jar files internally