# How to set up mongodb cammands?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I set up the path in the environment variables to the mongo.exe and mongod.exe but still i am not able to use the commands mongo and mongod to start it directly, the command prompt is not recognising the commands mongo and mongod, what should i do to use these commands?

Comment: What is the operating system and version, and which shell/interpreter are you using?

Comment: i am using windows 10 64bits and i am using mongodb 4.2

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access mongod and mongo as command from command prompt then instead of setting path in environment variable you need to create aliases in command prompt [refer this for creating alias in command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt).

Or go to directory where mongod.exe available and execute it.

Otherwise,simple way is download 'mongoDB compass' which is GUI for MongoDB.