# Windows Batch Files: How can I append to a *.bat or *.cmd file from within itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, doskey

I'm trying to implement a slight modification to the code provided by @Argyll in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt#answer-21040825), specifically changing:

```
DOSKEY alias=notepad %USERPROFILE%\Dropbox\alias.cmd
```

to:

```
doskey alias=echo doskey $*>>%0
```

But the redirection fails when I use this new alias, and I simply get `doskey <whatever I typed after alias>` echo'ed to the console as per usual :-(

As you can probably tell, I'm a batch script noob, so what am I doing wrong here? MTIA :-)

Comment: Proper escape it with carets `doskey alias=echo doskey $*^>^>%%0` or `doskey alias=echo doskey $*^^^>^^^>%%0`, depends on what you want

Comment: Thank you kind sir! Please ignore my previous comment if you saw it before deletion; the only part of what you wrote that doesn't work is the `%%0`, which I find quite strange, but meh I guess it's not hard to type ~20 extra characters once ;) If you could add some more background information to a proper answer re: why/how it works, and the `%%0` issue, I'd gladly mark it as the accepted answer. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the redirection, else the redirection is active in the moment where you call `doskey alias=echo doskey $*>>%0`, it appends the output of the doskey command (which is always empty in this case) to the current batch file.

But if you modify your line to

```
doskey alias=echo doskey $*^>^> "%~f0"
```

This creates a macro named `alias` like

```
alias=echo doskey $* >> C:\myfull\path\to\myBatch.bat
```

I use `%~f0` for the full path, else the macro could be defined like

```
alias=echo doskey $* >> myBatch.bat
```

That will obviously fail, if you're not in the correct directory

Comment: Awesome! TYVM again :D Hope these trying times are treating you as good as possible.