# How do I run npx commands without prefixing `npx`

Tags: javascript, npm

For example when I run `gulp` I don't have to do `npx gulp`.

I can omit the `npx` and just run `gulp`

How do I do this for my own package?

I've added `mycommand` to the package npm `bin` config, but I still always have to do `npx mycommand` for it to work.

Comment: It’s most likely that you can just run gulp because you installed gulp-cli globally, which is a pattern you probably shouldn’t mimic (it’s inefficient, involves global packages which you can otherwise entirely avoid, and more complicated than the following alternative). Consider a shell alias `alias mycommand='npx mycommand'`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your operating system.  On a UNIX-based OS (ie. Linux or Mac) you can use the `alias` command:

```
$ alias gulp="npx gulp"
```

For the rest of your terminal session, you can then run:

```
$ gulp
```

to run `npx gulp`.  However, whenever you restart your terminal program, you'll lose the alias.

To make the alias permanent, you need to add the `alias` command to the appropriate start-up file (eg. `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc.) for your OS.  Simply copy/paste the exact command you used before, at the end of that file, save, and restart your terminal.  You'll have the alias permanently.

Aliases in Windows are also possible, but are a bit trickier; see [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt).

Comment: This is a good generic solution, but not best practice with npx

Comment: "not the best practice" how? This is far better than installing things globally, the leading cause of "works on my machine" problems...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `npx gulp` for `gulp` because it is installed globally

So, there's `gulp.cmd`, `gulp.ps1` and `gulp` starting `npx gulp` somewhere in PATH, so you can run them from there

> this answer is low effort, feel free to edit it

Answer (score 0):

if you install gulp globally:
`npm i -g gulp`
you will be able to just run `gulp`

Comment: You should never install things globally. It's the main cause of "works on my machine" problems. Everyone ends up with their own, unique, unversioned toolset instead of having it checked in to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid answers suggesting global installs (`npm install -g`). Global installs guarantee that everyone working on a project has their own unique set of tools, and the reason companies end up with huge wiki pages on "how to get the project working locally".

You mention the "bin config", but perhaps you're misunderstanding that one. That's not for specifying commands that your app will use. If you were making a cli application, the [bin section in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#bin) is where you would specify the commands **exported** by your project. For example, `gulp` [exports the `gulp` command](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/818bd73e5da1ad69f43eef84214c98d6392a73e4/package.json#L22-L24) like:

```json
  "bin": {
    "gulp": "./bin/gulp.js"
  },
```

Instead, you would add dependencies needed by your application to `devDependencies`. This ensures that everyone using the project will get the same version of all of the tools, such as `gulp`, `tsc`
Using `npx` is a far better solution because you can add everything the project needs in `devDependencies`, and `npx` will use that version. For the common command line tools, an alias such as @machineghost suggests is a better way to go, but to expand on it a bit:

- Sometimes, the name of the command is different from the name of the package. In those cases, the alias can use:

```
alias tsc='npx --package=typescript tsc'
```

Normally, when running `npx`, it will prompt to install if there is not a version found in the current project. This is often a good safeguard, because  it reminds you to add it to the `devDependencies` of the project. However, if you really want it to "just work" like a global install, you can add the "yes" flag:

```
alias command=`npx -y gulp`
```

This will use the version specified in the current project if present, but install it and run it directly if not.