# Visual studio: How to open a specific solution directly from command line?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to open a specific solution (.sln) in visual studio ***directly from the command line***.

Using the command, I tried

```
devenv "full-path-to-sln-file.sln"
```

but it didn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you specify the full path to the sln file? Do you have multiple VS versions installed? Try to specify the full path to devenv.exe.

Answer (score 8):

You can just use **explorer**.exe !!
In your command line type in:

> explorer mysolution.sln

Answer (score 2):

Use the full path to the `devenv.exe` executable and the full path to the `sln` solution file, both wrapped in quotes and with a space in between. If your solution file is in a network path, make sure that it does not require authentication before accessing the destination folder.

```
C:\Users\YourWindowsUser>"D:\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "\\networkDirectory\profiles\Desktop\VisualStudioSolutions\Project999.sln"
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an open source application called [OpenVSSolution](https://github.com/djhmateer/OpenVSSolution) to do exactly this.

Essentially:

- Put this helper exe somewhere in your PATH
- The exe scans the current directory for a .sln file
- The exe opens devenv passing in the sln file

The explanation is on here:
https://davemateer.com/coding/2018/11/14/Open-visual-studio-from-command-line.html

I find this incredibly useful and is how I open all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a solution file with Visual Studio directly if you are within a folder that contains the solution file, looking for it recursively (Powershell 7.0) by doing the following:

Open powershell, type

```
echo $profile
```

Open up the location of your profile, save the below into it:

```
function vs
{
Get-ChildItem *.sln -Recurse | Invoke-Item
}
```

Then just type vs into a folder and it will go through the sub directories looking for the solution file and open one if found

Answer (score 0):

Try [WhatsNew](https://github.com/refactorsaurusrex/whats-new#open-visual-studio-solutions-from-the-command-line). From the readme:

> Why fish around for Visual Studio solution files using Windows Explorer when you can find and launch them from your terminal window with just three little letters? Run `sln` (an alias for `Open-Solution`) to recursively search your current working directory for a solution file and launch it, if one is found.

Answer (score 0):

for macOs I just use:

> open projectname.csproj

it will open it in visual studio 2019 for me